# Deploy React App to Azure using Jenkins for CI/CD

Tags: reactjs, azure, docker

I'm trying to use Azure and Jenkins together to push a React Docker image to the Azure Container Registry. It seems to work, however when I run the app using the image, I get a variety of errors in Azure. Typically the container will not start in time. What I don't understand is this process works just fine for a Node app that is literally just an Express server. But in React, there are problems.

I'm wondering if there is something missing in my understanding of how containers work in Azure. They always work locally but I've seen plenty of problems using them in Web Apps in Azure

Here is a common error that I have seen. Also I do not currently have a link to the repo, but it is simply the default `create-react-app`.

`failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1); Container ID 369884941 cannot be mapped to a host IDErr: 0, Message: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Container ID 36988941 cannot be mapped to a host ID`

More informatin that could be helpful:
When I push the images to Azure Container Registry via Jenkins, I have a web app with multiple deployment slots - development, staging, pilot, and production. When I use Jenkins to push an image, in Azure the Digest tag for latest is the same exact id for each environment. This is what I want, but is this problematic in Azure? Should each image truly have its own unique id even if it's the exact same image for each environment?

Something else that I have noticed is that I need to actually refresh the webpage for the app to restart, and this causes it to restart. I have enabled continuous deployment in the left blade under Deployment > Deployment Center > Continuous deployment. Shouldn't the app therefore refresh itself each time the image is updated, without me having to reload the page myself?

Comment: Can you add the errors to the question?

Comment: @Tony Yes will do

Answer (score 0):

> failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1); Container ID 369884941 cannot be mapped to a host IDErr: 0, Message: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Container ID 36988941 cannot be mapped to a host ID

- Recheck and verify if your application is containerized properly.
- Make sure to add `npm start` command in Docker file and also ensure that there are no errors while creating docker image.
- Sometimes, it happens due to `npm` versions too. Try to downgrade and check.
- Also, as mentioned in the [doc](https://circleci.com/docs/high-uid-error/), Identify and update the files with UID/GID, correct it and re-create the image.
- Command to find the file with high UID/GID

> $ find / ( -uid 1000000 )  -ls 2>/dev/null

---

I have created a simple reactjs application and Jenkins CI/CD pipeline to deploy my container to Azure App service.

*Deployed container from jenkins to Azure:*
[image]

*Logs of container which I have deployed from Jenkins CI/CD pipeline:*
[image]

**Result:**

*Container of my react application is running successfully as shown below:*

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response Pravallika. I ended up using Azure support for this issue and it turns out that the npm version did have something to do with the id of the container being too high of a number. Can you identify which npm version you used to build the Docker image in your example?

Comment: @Robert, I have used Node version 16.15.1 and Npm version 9.6.3